# I need a fix for "LWMQTT_CONNECTION_DENIED" and "LWMQTT_NOT_AUTHORIZED"

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, jwt, google-cloud-iot

I am using this

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-iot-arduino/tree/master/examples/Esp32-lwmqtt [Github link]

to configure the default ESP32 built-in LED using Google Cloud IoT Core's 'Update config' feature from the Console. But when I populated all the 3 files with necessary data and ran I am getting the following error in Serial Monitor of Arduino. The irony is, when I changed the project details from a new mail-id, everything is working fine. Can someone please help me in finding, why some projects are not working with this code

Below is an image of my problem for your reference

[image: Link to my error in image format]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens whenever you have a parameter configured incorrectly in the MQTT connection properties. I recommend you print your Client ID string and verify the JWT payloads match what the MQTT bridge expects.

The client ID should be in the following format:

```
projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/<REGION>/registries/<REGISTRY_ID>/devices/<DEVICE_ID>
```

Verify that everything configured in the client header matches what is configured in the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iot).

For the device JWT, you can verify it from [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) and should ensure the aud and alg payloads are [what is expected for AuthN](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/jwts).

A few other conditions that can cause disconnections:

- Connecting to the wrong topic (e.g. wrong device ID)
- Connecting using the wrong QoS

These should not affect you as you're working from the Arduino client though.

Comment: Actually! In my case, ec key was an issue. I recreated them and then everything is fine